# C++ When comparing, pass class as pointer or normally?

Tags: c++

I'm quite new to C++, and since I want my code to be good, I have a small question, let's say I have a function

```
UI::GetColor(CClass Class) 
{
  if (Class.m_Something)
       return 0;

  return 1;
}
```

Is it better to pass the CClass as a pointer, so it's not being copied or not? I saw a lot of code using different styles of that and I'm kind of confused which one is better and why. Thanks for answers.

Comment: Pass it by (const) reference in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function should be written as follows:

```
class UI {
   ...
   int GetColor(const CClass &c) const {
      if (c.m_Something) {
         return 0;
      } 
      return 1;
   }

}
```

The reference avoids an unnecessary copy; the `const`-parameter states that the parameter will not be changed; the `const`-function declarator states that the function will not change the `this`-object (i.e. the `UI`-instance on which it is called).

Comment: To avoid branches and get a linear flow of the logic you could use: `int GetColor(const CClass& c) const { return c.m_something ? 0 : 1; }`. Some people don't like the `?:` operator, so feel free to ignore it.